# Swift multipart/form-data upload with append String Array to body (Issue: Array goes as String to Server)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, multipartform-data

Im trying to send an String Array to the server in a multipart request using Alamofire Swift library, i tried several ways to encode the array but most of the time it goes as a string. can anyone help me with this. except the array sending image uploading and other values goes fine to the server. below is my code.

```
var parameters: Parameters = [
        "UEmail": userObj.email,
        "UFirstName": fName,
        "ULastName": lName,
        "VisitedCountries": getVisitedCountryCodeList() //return String array
    ]

let headers: HTTPHeaders
    headers = ["Content-type": "multipart/form-data"]

    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            if let subArray = value as? NSArray {
                do {
                    if(key == "VisitedCountries"){
                        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.getVisitedCountryCodeList(), options: [])
                        multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "VisitedCountries" )
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("error msg")
                }
            } else {
                multipartFormData.append((value as! NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key )
            }
        }

        if(self.selectedProfileImage != nil){
            guard let imgData = self.selectedProfileImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 2) else { return }
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "file", fileName: "image.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }

    },usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
      to: "\(Constants.SERVER_URL)\(Constants.USER_EDIT)",
      method: .post,
      headers: headers).response{ response in
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        if(response.data != nil) {

            do {
                if let jsonData = response.data {
                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                    print(parsedData)
                }

            } catch {
                print("error msg")
            }
        } else {
            print("user edit response2 \(response) end")
        }
    }
```

above is my AF.upload code. array append is the section i have the issue.
here is the array appending code.

```
//getVisitedCountryCodeList() returns string array  

let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.getVisitedCountryCodeList(), options: []) 
multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "VisitedCountries" )
```

i tried below code as well

```
multipartFormData.append(try JSONEncoder().encode(self.getVisitedCountryCodeList()), withName: key )
```

the below is what server gets, which is string not array

```
"VisitedCountries"=>"[\"ALG\",\"ARG\"]"
```

but i need to send like this

```
"VisitedCountries"=> ["ALG","ARG"]
```

Comment: Its an array of strings under the key „VisitedCountries”. What is the format you’d expect?

Comment: "VisitedCountries"=> ["ALG","ARG"] . i expect this. specially without the outer "[]" quotes. p.s- im not a backend dev  @Losiowaty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found an answer by myself, just have to do a small trick with the key value. below is the code.

```
for code in self.getVisitedCountryCodeList(){
    if let codeData = code.data(using: .utf8) {
        multipartFormData.append(codeData, withName: key+"[]" )
    }
}
```

**key+"[]"** or **"VisitedCountries[]"** is the trick here it automatically catch its as an array and add the next values to it.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the accepted solution only worked for sending one object in the array. For more than one item, the array needed to be sent as `"code[]="ALG","ARG""`.

The accepted answer generates multiple arrays with one item each, like: `"code[]="ALG" "code[]="ARG""`. What worked for me was to first generate a comma separated string of all the array objects, convert that to Data and append that to the MultiPartFormData in one time.

The alternative code:

```
        let key = "countryCodes"
        let array = ["ALG", "ARG"]
        let arrayString = array.joined(separator: ",")

        if let arrayData = arrayString.data(using: .utf8) {
            formData.append(arrayData, withName: key+"[]" )
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In header change `Content-type` to `application/json` from `multipart/form-data`. `Content-type` of the request tells the server in which format you are sending the data.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-type": "application/json"]
```

Comment: I need to upload an image as well. 
just tried, still the same :D

Comment: @LahiruPinto 
Check [jpegData(compressionQuality:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata)

compressionQuality - expressed as a value from 0.0 to 1.0